# Power consumption of mining rig?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, electrical-grid

I plan to buy a mining rig, with 750 watt PSU. It will be turned on for 24/7. I had like to calculate, how much kw/h will it spend per month?

Comment: Maybe 750*30*24/1000 ?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Since I lack the reputation to write comments:

The electricity cost of mining is way higher than the earnings. Small scale mining is not profitable anymore for a long time already, mining farms have 20000 graphics cards or something in that range.

Beyond that: a 750 Watt PSU will (at its limit) consume 0.75kWh per hour and thus 126 kWh per week, roughly 500 kWh per month. How much the mining rig actually draws from the socket depends on the components you use.